# Redirect to liferay private pages, post login

Tags: liferay-6

All,
I have a post login hook which will redirect the user to his private pages , user has only private pages and no public , community , origination pages.

Problem:
After login , user closes the browser tab (not log-out) , and then he opens the new tab and try to access the portal again. As the session is still alive , liferay doesnt prompt the login page , instead it takes the user to some default welcome page.

In these situations i still want the user to redirected too his private pages. any one know how to handle this situation ?

Answer (score 0):

You can handle this situation via a ServicePreAction Hook and/or adjusting the way your site landing pages are arranged.  It is not an uncommon situation and the solution is dependent on how your site should behave.